# No targets specified and no makefile found in Nominatim installation

Tags: make, makefile

I'm trying to setting up my own OpenStreetMap server and i followed the official tutorial in Wikipedia and one other tutorial. First i clone `Nominatim` from GIT and i build it by taping :

```
 cd Nominatim/
 cd module/
 sudo make
 cd ..
 cd nominatim/
 sudo ./autogen.sh
 sudo ./configure
```

and everything was fine till now. When i tape `sudo make` i got this :

```
make: **** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

How do i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the `./autogen.sh` and `./configure` steps completed successfully? normally, these steps would result in generation of a Makefile. If you're not sure, run `./configure` again and post the last few lines of its output.

Comment: well i got this error and i skipped saying that it can't be a real problem : "checking for postgreSQL libraries...configure : error : postgresql server development library not found"  maybe that the real problem

Comment: Yes that is almost certainly the real problem: make sure you have installed all the [Ubuntu/Debian dependencies](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian) listed in the wiki page, especially the `postgresql` ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `postgresql`, so after installing:

- `postgresql-server-dev-9.3`
- `libpgtcl-dev`

The problem is solved. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to fix, you're just acted unfavorably.

Maybe it's safer if you delete the directory first and checking out again: `git clone git@github.com:twain47/Nominatim.git` and `cd Nominatim`

1. If checking out from git run:

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   ```
2. Compile Nominatim:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   ```
3. Get OSM data and import:

   ```
   ./utils/setup.php --osm-file <your planet file> --all
   ```
4. Point your webserver to the ./website directory.

[Source](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim/blob/master/README)

Comment: I don't solve the problem yet, i'm trying to re-install the packages and find the source of the problem.